# Append dynamically generated HTML to product description tab (2.1)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, catalog, product-view

Currently I'm working on a Magento 2.1 webshop which deals in car parts. Each part should should a list of car models that can use this part. This list is generated dynamically based on a set of filters attached to the products.

Generating the list items is no problem, but now I want to show these items in a list below the description. The content has to be appended to the contents of the `product.info.description` block.

---

So far I've managed to add the list as a separate tab using the following code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="MyModule\CarLabels"
                   name="carlabels.tab"
                   as="carlabels"
                   template="MyModule::carlabels.phtml"
                   group="detailed_info">
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Since I don't want an extra tab, I've also tried to add the block after the description block. The code below did not work:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="MyModule\CarLabels"
                   name="product.info.carlabels"
                   template="MyModule::carlabels.phtml"
                   after="product.info.description">
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

---

In `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` you can see that the description block calls a method called `getDescription()`, so I'm thinking one might be able to overwrite this method and append to it without destroying the original content?

**Reference (taken from Magento source code):**

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
            <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
        <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</block>
```

---

**I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction here.** Does anyone know how to append to the product description?

PS In case you didn't notice yet, I'm a Magento-newb. Googling this issue always seems to lead back to articles about creating a new tab, which is not the goal in this case (and something that I already created as a working test case).

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you found an answer to your issue as it has been over 3 months but as I was having the same issue and stumbled upon this ticket I thought I'd mention my fix.

As you mention, trying to update the layout to include your own block, was not working.

What I had to do was create a plugin and append to the _toHtml() function:

di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<type name="\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes">
    <plugin name="Name_Goes_Here"
            type="File\Dir\Plugin\AttributesOutputPlugin"/>
</type>

</config>
```

Then create the Plugin file File\Dir\Plugin\AttributesOutputPlugin.php:

```
<?php

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes;

class AttributesOutputPlugin
{
/** @var View */
private $productPdfView;

public function __construct(YourBlock $blockName)
{
    $this->blockName = $blockName;
}

public function afterToHtml(Attributes $subject, string $html)
{
    $htmlAppend = $this->blockName->generateHtmlToAppend();
    return $html . $htmlAppend;
}
```

Hopefully this might help.

Regards,
Mark

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I am no longer in the position to check this answer, as we've moved on to other solutions. I hope someone else will find this thread and use it to their advantage.